# Apache Velocity not replacing few variables sometimes

Tags: velocity

We are using Velocity to create email templates. For that, we are adding all the required parameters to a HashMap and that HashMap we are adding to the VelocityContext object. It generally works fine, but sometimes(not always) few variables are not being replaced by velocity. I also checked that these variables did exist in HashMap before being added to the context. Please suggest what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess the reason without seeing the code... typos? name collision?

There's a debugging technique (if you don't use the SecureUberspector) which consists in displaying `$object.class.name` from *inside* the template.